# When SAXParserFactory.newSAXParser() throws SAXException?

Tags: java

`SAXParserFactory.newSAXParser()` throws `ParserConfigurationException` and `SAXException`. In [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newSAXParser%28%29) I'm not able to find out reasons why `SAXException` should be thrown.

When `SAXParserFactory.newSAXParser()` throws `SAXException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newSAXParser%28%29) points out the `newSAXParser` method is abstract. However, the `newInstance` method creates a `SAXParserFactoryImpl` object that `extends` the `SAXParserFactory` class and overrides the `newSAXParser` method.

The `newSAXParser` method here throws only `ParserConfigurationException`, but if you look inside it catches a `SAXException` which is translated to `ParserConfigurationException`.
This exception is thrown in the `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl` constructor by the `init` method.

I have searched through the full java 5 source code and there is no other class that extends the SAXParserFactory. 
So basically, the method you asked for never throws a `SAXException`. 
However, if it is thrown on the way, it is caught and translated into a `ParserConfigurationException`.

Comment: I have found another implementations. All implementations do same. They translates `SAXException` to `ParserConfigurationException`. I'm developing on Android's Dalvik. It catches even `Exception`. Really do not know why `SAXParserFactory.newSAXParser` declares it throws `SAXException`. However from code I can see now that parser implementation throws only `SAXException`.

Comment: I do not know either. A possible explanation is that in a previous version the `SAXException` was not translated ... I don't know

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newSAXParser%28%29):

```
Throws:
ParserConfigurationException - if a parser cannot be created which satisfies the requested configuration.
SAXException - for SAX errors.
```

So it seems like SAXException is thrown for every error in the SaxParser which is not Parsing Configuration error.